# Jquery html function not working properly until remove called

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am facing a problem where `$('element').html('<p>Some HTML</p>');` is not working properly. After executing `$('element').remove();` function the `$('element').html();` is working fine.
Example Code below:

```
<div id="someId"><p>Html before</p></div>
//html() Not working
$('#someId').html("<h1>Some changed Html</h1>");


$('#someId').remove();
//After remove() the html() also works
$('#someId').html("<h1>Some changed Html</h1>");
```

Comment: I would assume you have multiple elements in the DOM with the same `#someId` value, which is invalid. When you call `remove()` the first one is removed. When you then call `html()` again, the element you expect to update is selected. To check this, do a search in the DOM inspector for the id you're trying to find. If there is more than one, that's the problem.

Comment: In general, IDs should be unique. And jQuery assumes that this is true, so ID selectors will only select the first match.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RoryMcCrossan. You are right and the DOM consits multiple elements with same ID. It's fine now.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working